# Writing Javascript If condition in a dynamically creating HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My JS

```
for (var i=0; i<result.length ;i++) {

                var selectValue = $("#ProductCode option[value=" + result[i].PRODUCT_CODE + "]").text();

                html += '<tr id="tr-'+tblcounter+'" class=""><td class="pc">'
                           + selectValue
                           + '</td><td class="oc">'
                           + result[i].ORDER_QTY
                            + '</td><td class="oc">'
                           + result[i].DELIVERY_QTY
                            + '</td><?php if($usertype == "ANE"){?><td class="oc">'
                           + result[i].RECIEVED_QTY
                            + '</td><?php } ?><td class="operations"><a href="#" class="editlines" id="'+result[i].LINE_NUMBER+'" onClick="editRow(this);"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/edit_icon.png" height="20px" width="20px"></a>'

                           + '</td></tr>';
                   tblcounter++;
              }
              $('#recvLines').append(html);
```

In the above table I need to display the last column if my Javascript condition satisfies, otherwise I dont want to display it.

For example

```
 + '</td><?php } ?>'+if("something" == "something")+'<td class="operations"><a href="#" class="editlines" id="'+result[i].LINE_NUMBER+'" onClick="editRow(this);"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/edit_icon.png" height="20px" width="20px"></a>'

                           + '</td></tr>';
```

If I write the if condition like above the code is not working.
Any ideas?? Thanks

Comment: php scripts will not be processed with in javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ternary operator

```
+ '<tr>' + (x == 5 ? '<td>true</td>' : '<td>false</td>') + '</tr>'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 + '</td><?php } ?>'+ ("something" == "something" ? '<td class="operations"><a href="#" class="editlines" id="'+result[i].LINE_NUMBER+'" onClick="editRow(this);"><img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/edit_icon.png" height="20px" width="20px"></a></td>' : '') + '</tr>';
```

Might do the trick.